# Faster way of storing Excel worksheet to system.data.datatable using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to find a faster way to read an XML file that can be opened in Excel 2010. I cannot immediately read the XML file using readxml method because it contains Workbook, style, cell, data and other tags. So my approach was to open it in Excel then get the data on sheet 2 only. The sample file contains 9,000+ rows and takes about 2mins 49secs to store in a datatable. The actual file has 25,000+ rows. This is what I have tried:

```
private void bulkInsert()
        {
            var s = new Stopwatch();

            s.Start();
            try
            {
                KillExcel();
                GCollector();
                Excel.Application app = null;
                app = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
                Excel.Workbook book = null;

                book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"my directory for the file");

                sheet = (Worksheet)book.Sheets[2];
                sheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                var xlRange = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[sheet.Rows.Count, 1];
                int lastRow = (int)xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
                int newRow = lastRow + 1;
                var cellrow = newRow;
                int columns = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
                Excel.Range test = sheet.UsedRange;
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Node_SegmentName");
                dt.Columns.Add("Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("Sub-Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("Description");
                dt.Columns.Add("Parameter_DataIdentifier");
                dt.Columns.Add("RuntimeValue");
                dt.Columns.Add("Category");
                dt.Columns.Add("Result");
                dt.TableName = "SsmXmlTable";
//slow part
                for (i = 0; i < lastRow; i++)
                {
                    DataRow excelRow = dt.NewRow();

                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    {
                        excelRow[j] = test.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value2;

                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(excelRow);

                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                ds.WriteXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + String.Format("\\XMLParserOutput{0}.xml", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-d-yyyy")));



                DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
                reportData.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + String.Format("\\XMLParserOutput{0}.xml", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-d-yyyy")));
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YOURCOMPUTERNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASE;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0");
                connection.Open();
                SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
                sbc.DestinationTableName = "Test";
                sbc.WriteToServer(reportData.Tables["SsmXmlTable"]);
                connection.Close();
                s.Stop();
                var duration = s.Elapsed;

                MessageBox.Show(duration.ToString() + " bulk insert way");
                MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables["SsmXmlTable"].Rows.Count.ToString());//439 rows
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                KillExcel();
                GCollector();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + i.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Without the reading from Excel part, the insertion of data using bulk copy only takes a couple of seconds (0.5secs for 449 rows).

Comment: Don't read each cell over COM.  Instead read the entire sheet into memory first and then iterate over the array.  Look up UsedRange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who are encountering the same issue, what I did was:

- save the xml as an xlsx file
- use oledb to read the xlsx file
- store in dataset using OleDbAdapter (Fill() method)
- bulk insert

Here is the code that I used to do this (change the connection string):

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
string sSheetName = null;
string sConnection = null;
System.Data.DataTable sheetData = new System.Data.DataTable();
System.Data.DataTable dtTablesList = default(System.Data.DataTable);
OleDbConnection oleExcelConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestXmlParser\TestXmlParser\bin\Debug\ConsolidatedSSMFiles.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
oleExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
oleExcelConnection.Open();
dtTablesList = oleExcelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

if (dtTablesList.Rows.Count > 0)
{
sSheetName = dtTablesList.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
}
dtTablesList.Clear();
dtTablesList.Dispose();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSheetName))
{
OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [TEST$]", oleExcelConnection);
sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
} s.Stop();
var duration = s.Elapsed;


oleExcelConnection.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = sheetData;
MessageBox.Show(sheetData.Rows.Count.ToString()+"rows - "+ duration.ToString());
```

This reads 25000+ rows of excel data to a datable in approx. 1.9 to 2.0 seconds.